# passing data from <form:select> to my controller is being sent with the value null Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to get the value of the selected element in my dropdownList to save it into my database but the data is being passed 'null'.

I've searched in these post and over the web but I could not being able yet to find the answer: [How to pass data from <form:select> Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218693/how-to-pass-data-from-formselect-spring-mvc) and [How to Pass <Select> and <input> data from View to a Controller (Spring MVC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28200021/how-to-pass-select-and-input-data-from-view-to-a-controller-spring-mvc).

Here is my view:

```
<form:form action="${urlcallBankAddAction}" method="POST" onsubmit="return validar(this)" modelAttribute="banco">
    <input type="text" name="bancoNombre" />
    <input type="text" name="bancoCodigoVisa" maxlength="8" onkeypress="return isNumber(event);" />
    <form:select path="descripcion" name="bancoPadre" id="banks-description" onchange="selectValue()">
            <form:options items="${resultList}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="descripcion"/>
    </form:select> 
</form:form>
```

My controller (by the way, you all may see that it has the property 'required = false', yes because it can be null but that logic I'll apply it later, once I got the value from the selected option):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addAction", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String agregarBanco(HttpServletRequest request,
        @RequestParam("bancoNombre") String bancoNombre,
        @RequestParam("bancoCodigoVisa") int bancoCodigoVisa,
        @RequestParam("bancoCodigoSudeban") String bancoCodigoSudeban,
        @RequestParam(value = "bancoPadre", required = false) String bancoPadre,
        ModelMap model,
        HttpSession session){

    try{
        String valorSesion = (String) session.getAttribute("acceso");//Se valida el inicio de sesion
        if(valorSesion.equals("1")){//Se valida el inicio de sesion
            Banco banco = new Banco();
            logger.error("****************************");
            logger.error("BANCO PADREEEEEE " + bancoPadre + "      " + bancoNombre + " " + bancoCodigoVisa);
            logger.error("****************************");
            banco.setDescripcion(bancoNombre);
            banco.setCodigoVisa(bancoCodigoVisa);
            banco.setCodigoSudeban(bancoCodigoSudeban);

            bancoService.agregarBanco(banco);

            model.addAttribute("status", "Banco guardado con exito.");

            return "redirect:/banks/details";
        } else{
            //MANDAR A PAGINA DE ERROR
            return "redirect:/unauthorized";
        }
    } catch(NullPointerException n){//Se valida el inicio de sesion
        //MANDAR A PAGINA DE ERROR
        return "redirect:/unauthorized";
    }
```

and my model just in case:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name = "cod_visa")
private int codigoVisa;

@Column(name = "CodSud")
private String codigoSudeban;

@Column(name = "descripcion")
private String descripcion;

@Column(name = "id_padre")
private Integer idPadre;
```

When I send the data to my controller, you can see I and logging those parameters that I am supposed to get from my view but this is what I am getting

```
2016-07-14 09:14:21 ERROR BancosController:96 - ****************************
2016-07-14 09:14:21 ERROR BancosController:97 - BANCO PADREEEEEE null           test 32423
2016-07-14 09:14:21 ERROR BancosController:98 - ****************************
```

Here is a portiong of what I got on the web by looking 'view page source' and i would like to take the value and just to test it the plain text.

```
<select id="banks-description" name="descripcion" name="bancoPadre" onchange="selectValue()">
            <option value="27">100% BANCO, BANCO UNIVERSAL, C.A. DE OSMAN</option>
 </select>
```

and if it is worth it, here a capture of the view
[image]

Hope you guys could give a hand with this. I dont know what I am missing.

**EDIT**

I add the whole code view

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags"%>

<spring:url value="/banks/deleteAction" var="urlcallBankDeleteAction"/>
<spring:url value="/banks/addAction" var="urlcallBankAddAction"/>

<form:form action="${urlcallBankAddAction}" method="POST" onsubmit="return validar(this)" modelAttribute="banco">
<div style="color:RGB(0,32,159); font-weight:bold;"><fmt:message key="banks.addTitle" /></div>
<div class="field mandatory">
    <spring:message text="${status}" /><br />
    <label><fmt:message key="banks.nombre" /></label>
    <input type="text" name="bancoNombre" />
</div>
<div class="field mandatory" style="display:inline-block;">
    <label><fmt:message key="banks.visaCode" /></label>
    <input type="text" name="bancoCodigoVisa" maxlength="8" onkeypress="return isNumber(event);" />
            <label><fmt:message key="banks.sudebanCode" /></label>
    <input type="text" name="bancoCodigoSudeban" maxlength="4" onkeypress="return isNumber(event);" />
</div>
    <br/>
    <div class="field mandatory" style="display: inline; width: 150px;">
        <label>Entidad Interna: <input type="radio" name="padre" id="entidad-interna" value="interna" onclick="disabledList()"  disabled=true checked/></label> 
        <label>Entidad Externa: <input type="radio" name="padre" id="entidad-externa" value="externa" onclick="enableList()" disabled=true/></label>
    </div>
    <br><br>        
    <div class="field mandatory" style="display: inline-block; width: 150px;">
        <input type="checkbox" name="tiene-padre" id="tiene-padre" value="tiene-padre" onchange="checkList()" /> Tiene padre
       <form:select path="descripcion" name="bancoPadre" id="banks-description" onchange="selectValue()">
            <form:options items="${resultList}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="descripcion"/>
        </form:select> 
    </div>
    <br><br>         
     <%-- <form:select path="descripcion" name="bancoPadre" id="banks-description" onchange="selectValue()">         
            <form:options items="${resultList}"  />
         </form:select>--%>        
<t:button-submit />
</form:form>
<table class="smart" >
    <caption><fmt:message key="banks.listTitle" /></caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ><fmt:message key="banks.visaCode" /></th>
            <th ><fmt:message key="banks.sudebanCode" /></th>
            <th ><fmt:message key="banks.nombre" /></th>
            <th ><fmt:message key="banks.operation" /></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <c:forEach items="${resultList}" var="c" varStatus="iteracion">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>${c.codigoVisa}</td>
            <td>${c.codigoSudeban}</td>
            <td>${c.descripcion}</td>
            <td><a href="${urlcallBankDeleteAction}/${c.codigoSudeban}" onclick="return confirm('¿Está seguro de eliminar este banco?');"><fmt:message key="banks.operation1" /></td>
        </tr>
</c:forEach>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: nup... because in that list I have the banks showed in my dropdownlist

Comment: you can add a logger to your controller method to display to value of the item selected..

Comment: FuSsa, sorry I dont get it.. what do you mean? I am loggin this "logger.error("BANCO PADREEEEEE " + bancoPadre" which is the form:select what I am getting from my view

Comment: 'resultList' is a list of what ? mean type ? because description is String in your class

Comment: It is a List<Banco> and Banco is the Model. The one I pasted above but incomplete

Comment: can you post the code of all your page and not just form:select?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this Example this:

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="user" class="form-horizontal">
        <form:input type="hidden" path="id" id="id"/>



        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <form:input type="text" path="lastName" id="lastName" class="form-control input-sm" />
                    <div class="has-error">
                        <form:errors path="lastName" class="help-inline"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>





        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="email">Email</label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <form:input type="text" path="email" id="email" class="form-control input-sm" />
                    <div class="has-error">
                        <form:errors path="email" class="help-inline"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="userProfiles">Roles</label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <form:select path="userProfiles" items="${roles}" multiple="true" itemValue="id" itemLabel="type" class="form-control input-sm" />
                    <div class="has-error">
                        <form:errors path="userProfiles" class="help-inline"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-actions floatRight">
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${edit}">
                        <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"/> or <a href="<c:url value='/list' />">Cancel</a>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                        <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"/> or <a href="<c:url value='/list' />">Cancel</a>
                    </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form:form>
```

AppController:

```
     @RequestMapping(value = { "/newuser" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String saveUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult result,
                ModelMap model) {

            if (result.hasErrors()) {
                return "registration";
            }
            userService.saveUser(user);

            return "registrationsuccess";
    }
```

Comment: If I try that approach I get thw whole object List<Banco> and the description which is what I want to show.

Comment: so your logger dont display the null value ?

Comment: yes, It still displays null.. btw I added the code you requested

Comment: any idea of what is happening here? :S

Comment: answer updated..this example is working for me..can you try the same approach ?

Comment: Still receiving null u.u

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution using the developer tool integrated with Mozilla.

The problem: I was trying to get a value from the request which did not exist in it.

```
@RequestParam(value = "bancoPadre", required = false) String bancoPadre
```

So by changing the code above to the code below I was able to get the value from the selected item inside the dropdownList

```
@RequestParam(value = "descripcion", required = false) String bancoPadre
```

This is the logging which demostrates the value

```
2016-07-14 13:45:35 ERROR BancosController:96 - ****************************
2016-07-14 13:45:35 ERROR BancosController:97 - BANCO PADREEEEEE 30      cleider 2342
2016-07-14 13:45:35 ERROR BancosController:98 - ****************************
```

And here's the image where I realized I was getting the  wrong parameter.

[image]